# Fragments with Interface class in Android

Tags: android, interface, android-fragments, media-player, android-videoview

I am having issue , how to use the interface class in fragment class. 
while implementing interface with fragment it not works fine.

I have an **1 fragment activity** and **2 fragments**. take as **fragment 1,fragment 2**.

By default **fragment 1**(video view its playing video) is inflated in frame layout in half of the page fragment activity.
by clicking the button in activity, **fragment 2** is inflated the next half of the page.

while clicking the button in **fragment 2** fragment 1 content need a change so i used interface to stop the video in **fragment 1** but it is not working. if i implement the interface in fragment activity its working, but in fragment class it is not working.. help me to do this..

**fragment activity**

```
public class main extends FragmentActivity implements Interface_Class{
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle arg0) {
        super.onCreate(arg0);
        setContentView(R.layout.activixml);
replaceFragment(new fragment1,R.id.fram1);
replaceFragment(new fragment2,R.id.fram2);
        }
    }
public void replaceFragment(Fragment fragment,int layout) {
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

        transaction.add(layout, fragment);
        transaction.commit();

    }
@Override
void setVideoOff(){
system.out.println("inside interface");
}
```

**Interface class**

```
interface Interface_Class {
void setVideoOff()
}
```

**fragment 1**

```
    public class feagment1 extends Fragment implements OnCompletionListener,Interface_Class{
     @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout, container, false);
     videoView = (VideoView) view.findViewById(R.id.videoView);
     Uri str=Uri.parse(path);
    // Video path
     videoView.setVideoURI(str); 
     videoView.requestFocus();
     videoView.start();
return view;
    }
     }
    @Override
    void setVideoOff(){
    system.out.println("inside interface");
videoView.stopPlayback();
    }
```

**fragment 2**

```
  public class fragment1 extends Fragment{
Interface_Class interface_Class
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.lay1, container, false);
interface_Class.setVideoOff();
return view;
}
    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        try {
            interface_Class = (Interface_Class) activity;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString());
        }
    }
    }
```

Comment: @Poovizhirajan.N http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html. the example is there in the doc

Comment: u making instance of fragment1 for adding it to fragment activity??

Comment: @AvinashKumarPankaj i m nt able to understand wat u asking

Comment: @Poovizhirajan.N communicate a boolean value from fragment2 say true to activity using interface on button click  and then communicate the same boolean value to fragment1. Now do the operation based on boolean value in fragment1. Quoting from docs All Fragment-to-Fragment communication is done through the associated Activity. Two Fragments should never communicate directly.

Comment: @Raghunandan thanku i try and tell u

Comment: @Raghunandan can u post how to update fragment from activity.

Comment: @Poovizhirajan.N check the docs has a clear example. just add a param  boolean like `nterface Interface_Class {
void setVideoOff(boolean value)
}` in fragment2 on button click `interface_Class.setVideoOff(true)` implement the interface in activity where you get the boolean value.

Comment: @Raghunandan i am getting value in activity how to pass to fragment

Comment: @Poovizhirajan.N check the topic **Deliver a Message to a Fragment** in the link provided

Comment: @Poovizhirajan.N have you read my previous comments http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html. or should i keep posting everything in comments again?

Answer (score 0):

in fragment activity(main class) do like this

```
    FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    fragment1 fragment = fragment1.newInstance(main.this);
    transaction.add(layout, fragment);
    transaction.commit();
```

and in fragment1 initaialize your interface class first like

```
 private Interface_class interface
```

and write before oncreateView()

```
  public static fragment1 newInstance(main main) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    fragment1 fragment = new fragment1();
    fragment.interface = main
    return fragment;
}
```

and then on fragment1 write on button clicklistener

```
 button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            interface.setVideoOff();
        }
    });
```

and in last in your fragment activity that is main class, write following code in your implemented interface

```
@override
void setVideoOff(){
//code to stop playing mediaplayer
    }
```